# Draw grid according to camera using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making an Agar.io clone and I am stuck in creating the grid background. I have seen questions about drawing background according to camera but they were all only for images.

Below is my code:

click = split

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = innerWidth;
var height = innerHeight;
var evt = "mousemove";
var touchX = 0;
var touchY = 0;

var config = {
  gameWidth: width,
  gameHeight: height,
  playerConfig: {
    mass: 10,
    hue: Math.round(Math.random() * 360),
    border: 6
  },
  virusConfig: {
    mass: 100,
    fill: "#33ff33",
    stroke: "#19D119",
    border: 10
  }
}

var maxSplits = 16;
var foods = [];
var viruses = [];
var clients = [];
var player = {
  blobs: [],
  lastSplit: 0,
  extent: {
    minX: 0,
    minY: 0,
    maxX: 0,
    maxY: 0
  }
};
var camera = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

function movePlayer() {
  for (var i = 0; i < player.blobs.length; i++) {
    var b = player.blobs[i];
    var e = player.extent;
    var x = touchX + camera.x - b.x;
    var y = touchY + camera.y - b.y;
    var dist = Math.hypot(x, y);

    b.velocity = {
      x: x / dist * b.speed,
      y: y / dist * b.speed
    };

    b.speed -= b.speed > 4 ? 0.25 : 0;
    b.speed -= b.speed > 4 ? 0.25 : 0;
    b.x += b.velocity.x * Math.min(1, Math.pow(x / b.r, 2));
    b.y += b.velocity.y * Math.min(1, Math.pow(y / b.r, 2));
    b.x = Math.min(Math.max(b.x, -config.gameWidth), config.gameWidth);
    b.y = Math.min(Math.max(b.y, -config.gameHeight), config.gameHeight);

    if (i == 0) {
      e.minX = e.maxX = b.x;
      e.minY = e.maxY = b.y;
    } else {
      e.minX = Math.min(b.x, e.minX);
      e.minY = Math.min(b.y, e.minY);
      e.maxX = Math.max(b.x, e.maxX);
      e.maxY = Math.max(b.y, e.maxY);
    }
  }
}

function handleSelfCollision() {
  for (var i = 0; i < player.blobs.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < player.blobs.length; j++) {
      if (j !== i && player.blobs[i] !== undefined) {
        var b1 = player.blobs[i];
        var b2 = player.blobs[j];
        var radii = b1.r + b2.r;
        var x = b2.x - b1.x;
        var y = b2.y - b1.y;
        var dist = Math.hypot(x, y);

        if (dist < radii) {
          if (player.lastSplit + 10000 > new Date().getTime()) {
            x /= dist;
            y /= dist;
            // test
            b1.x += ((b2.x - x * radii) - b1.x) * 0.6;
            b1.y += ((b2.y - y * radii) - b1.y) * 0.5;
            //test
          } else if (dist < radii * 0.75) {
            b1.mass = b1.mass + b2.mass;
            b1.r = massToRadius(b1.mass);
            player.blobs.splice(j, 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function handleVirusCollision() {
  for (var i = 0; i < viruses.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < player.blobs.length; j++) {
      var b = player.blobs[j];
      var v = viruses[i];
      var x = v.x - b.x;
      var y = v.y - b.y;
      var dist = Math.hypot(x, y);
      var radii = v.r + b.r;

      if (dist < radii) {
        b.r += v.r;
        viruses.splice(i, 1);
        if (player.blobs.length < maxSplits) {
          while (b.r >= defaultPlayerR * 2) {
            splitBlob(b);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function splitBlob(blob) {
  if (blob.mass >= config.playerConfig.mass * 2 && player.blobs.length < maxSplits) {
    blob.mass /= 2;
    blob.r = massToRadius(blob.mass)
    player.lastSplit = new Date().getTime();
    player.blobs.push({
      x: blob.x,
      y: blob.y,
      mass: blob.mass,
      r: massToRadius(blob.mass),
      speed: 20
    });
  }
}

function moveCamera() {
  var e = player.extent;
  camera.x = (e.maxX + e.minX) / 2;
  camera.y = (e.maxY + e.minY) / 2;
  camera.x -= width / 2;
  camera.y -= height / 2;
}

function addFood(num) {
  var rnd = random(1, 1.5);
  while (num--) {
    foods.push({
      x: random(-config.gameWidth, config.gameWidth),
      y: random(-config.gameHeight, config.gameHeight),
      mass: rnd,
      r: massToRadius(rnd),
      hue: Math.round(Math.random() * 360)
    });
  }
}

function addVirus(num) {
  while (num--) {
    viruses.push({
      x: random(-width, width),
      y: random(-height, height),
      mass: config.virusConfig.mass,
      r: massToRadius(config.virusConfig.mass)
    });
  }
}

function updateFood() {
  for (var i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < player.blobs.length; j++) {
      var b = player.blobs[j];
      var f = foods[i];
      var x = f.x - b.x;
      var y = f.y - b.y;
      var dist = Math.hypot(x, y);
      var radii = f.r + b.r;

      if (dist < radii) {
        b.mass += f.mass;
        b.r = massToRadius(b.mass);
        foods.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (foods.length < 100) {
    addFood(1);
  }
}

function drawPlayer(order) {
  var sortedArr = player.blobs.sort(function(b1, b2) {
    return b1.mass - b2.mass;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {
    var b = sortedArr[i];

    ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + config.playerConfig.hue + ", 100%, 50%)";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "hsl(" + config.playerConfig.hue + ", 100%, 45%)";
    ctx.lineWidth = config.playerConfig.border;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(b.x - camera.x, b.y - camera.y, b.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

function drawFood() {
  for (var i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
    var f = foods[i];

    ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + f.hue + ', 100%, 50%)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(f.x - camera.x, f.y - camera.y, f.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

function drawVirus() {
  for (var i = 0; i < viruses.length; i++) {
    var v = viruses[i];

    ctx.fillStyle = config.virusConfig.fill;
    ctx.strokeStyle = config.virusConfig.stroke;
    ctx.lineWidth = config.virusConfig.border;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(v.x - camera.x, v.y - camera.y, v.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

function drawPlatform(bgcol, borcol, thickness) {
  var x = -config.gameWidth - camera.x;
  var y = -config.gameHeight - camera.y;
  var w = 2 * config.gameWidth;
  var h = 2 * config.gameHeight;

  ctx.fillStyle = bgcol;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.lineWidth = thickness;
  ctx.strokeStyle = borcol;
  ctx.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
}

function drawBackground(col) {
  ctx.fillStyle = col;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

function drawGrid() {

}

function updateAndDraw() {
  movePlayer();
  moveCamera();
  updateFood();
  handleSelfCollision();
  //handleVirusCollision();

  drawBackground("#f2fbff");
  drawPlatform("#fff", "#000", 10);
  drawGrid();
  drawFood();
  drawPlayer();
  drawVirus();

  requestAnimationFrame(updateAndDraw);
}

function handleEvent(event) {
  touchX = event.clientX;
  touchY = event.clientY;
}

function random(min, max) {
  return (min + (Math.random() * (max - min)));
}

function massToRadius(mass) {
  return 4 + Math.sqrt(mass) * 6;
}

function startTheGame() {
  evt = width < 600 ? "click" : "mousemove";
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;

  addFood(100);
  addVirus(5);
  player.blobs.push({
    x: width / 2,
    y: height / 2,
    mass: config.playerConfig.mass,
    r: massToRadius(config.playerConfig.mass),
    speed: 8
  });

  //test
  canvas.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var blobs = player.blobs.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < blobs; i++) {
      if (blobs < maxSplits) {
        splitBlob(player.blobs[i]);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  });

  addEventListener("resize", function() {
    width = innerWidth;
    height = innerHeight
  });
  // test
  canvas.addEventListener(evt, handleEvent);
  updateAndDraw();
}


startTheGame();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<title>Gaario - A simple Agario clone</title>
<canvas>Awww! Your browser doesn't support canvas.</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid can be drawn by drawing the horizontal lines, and then adding the vertical ones. Using the `ctx.lineTo()` and `ctx.moveTo()` functions in combination with `ctx.beginPath()` and `ctx.stroke()` the grid is being drawn.

I filled the body of the drawGrid() function:

```
function drawGrid() {
    var gridSize = 30;    // define the space between each line
    var x = -config.gameWidth - camera.x;  // x start point of the field
    var y = -config.gameHeight - camera.y  // y start point of the field
    var width = 2 * config.gameWidth;
    var height = 2 * config.gameHeight;

    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(var i = 0; i * gridSize < height; i++) { // draw the horizontal lines
       ctx.moveTo(x, i * gridSize + y);
       ctx.lineTo(x + width, i * gridSize + y);
    }
    for(var i = 0; i * gridSize < width; i++) {  // draw the vertical lines
       ctx.moveTo(i * gridSize + x,  y);
       ctx.lineTo(i * gridSize + x, y + height);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

In the for loops to draw the lines we use the fact, that we know where the left upper corner of the container is. Variables `x` and `y` respectively.
So for drawing the vertical lines, we know that those point from the y-coordinate `y` to `y + height`.
We can calculate the x-coordinates for each line by running `i * gridSize + x` in the for loop.
For the first line from the left, `i = 0`, we get simply `x` back, which is our left border of the game field. 
The second line is drawn at `1 * gridSize + x`, the third at `2 * gridSize + x`, and so on.

By incrementing `i` for as long `i * gridSize < width` holds true, we draw all vertical lines in the game field.

```
for(var i = 0; i * gridSize < width; i++) {  // draw the vertical lines
   ctx.moveTo(i * gridSize + x,  y);
   ctx.lineTo(i * gridSize + x, y + height);
}
```

---

Below you find your code example, with the added function.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = innerWidth;
var height = innerHeight;
var evt = "mousemove";
var touchX = 0;
var touchY = 0;

var config = {
  gameWidth: width,
  gameHeight: height,
  playerConfig: {
    mass: 10,
    hue: Math.round(Math.random() * 360),
    border: 6
  },
  virusConfig: {
    mass: 100,
    fill: "#33ff33",
    stroke: "#19D119",
    border: 10
  }
}

var maxSplits = 16;
var foods = [];
var viruses = [];
var clients = [];
var player = {
  blobs: [],
  lastSplit: 0,
  extent: {
    minX: 0,
    minY: 0,
    maxX: 0,
    maxY: 0
  }
};
var camera = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

function movePlayer() {
  for (var i = 0; i < player.blobs.length; i++) {
    var b = player.blobs[i];
    var e = player.extent;
    var x = touchX + camera.x - b.x;
    var y = touchY + camera.y - b.y;
    var dist = Math.hypot(x, y);

    b.velocity = {
      x: x / dist * b.speed,
      y: y / dist * b.speed
    };

    b.speed -= b.speed > 4 ? 0.25 : 0;
    b.speed -= b.speed > 4 ? 0.25 : 0;
    b.x += b.velocity.x * Math.min(1, Math.pow(x / b.r, 2));
    b.y += b.velocity.y * Math.min(1, Math.pow(y / b.r, 2));
    b.x = Math.min(Math.max(b.x, -config.gameWidth), config.gameWidth);
    b.y = Math.min(Math.max(b.y, -config.gameHeight), config.gameHeight);

    if (i == 0) {
      e.minX = e.maxX = b.x;
      e.minY = e.maxY = b.y;
    } else {
      e.minX = Math.min(b.x, e.minX);
      e.minY = Math.min(b.y, e.minY);
      e.maxX = Math.max(b.x, e.maxX);
      e.maxY = Math.max(b.y, e.maxY);
    }
  }
}

function handleSelfCollision() {
  for (var i = 0; i < player.blobs.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < player.blobs.length; j++) {
      if (j !== i && player.blobs[i] !== undefined) {
        var b1 = player.blobs[i];
        var b2 = player.blobs[j];
        var radii = b1.r + b2.r;
        var x = b2.x - b1.x;
        var y = b2.y - b1.y;
        var dist = Math.hypot(x, y);

        if (dist < radii) {
          if (player.lastSplit + 10000 > new Date().getTime()) {
            x /= dist;
            y /= dist;
            // test
            b1.x += ((b2.x - x * radii) - b1.x) * 0.6;
            b1.y += ((b2.y - y * radii) - b1.y) * 0.5;
            //test
          } else if (dist < radii * 0.75) {
            b1.mass = b1.mass + b2.mass;
            b1.r = massToRadius(b1.mass);
            player.blobs.splice(j, 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function handleVirusCollision() {
  for (var i = 0; i < viruses.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < player.blobs.length; j++) {
      var b = player.blobs[j];
      var v = viruses[i];
      var x = v.x - b.x;
      var y = v.y - b.y;
      var dist = Math.hypot(x, y);
      var radii = v.r + b.r;

      if (dist < radii) {
        b.r += v.r;
        viruses.splice(i, 1);
        if (player.blobs.length < maxSplits) {
          while (b.r >= defaultPlayerR * 2) {
            splitBlob(b);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function splitBlob(blob) {
  if (blob.mass >= config.playerConfig.mass * 2 && player.blobs.length < maxSplits) {
    blob.mass /= 2;
    blob.r = massToRadius(blob.mass)
    player.lastSplit = new Date().getTime();
    player.blobs.push({
      x: blob.x,
      y: blob.y,
      mass: blob.mass,
      r: massToRadius(blob.mass),
      speed: 20
    });
  }
}

function moveCamera() {
  var e = player.extent;
  camera.x = (e.maxX + e.minX) / 2;
  camera.y = (e.maxY + e.minY) / 2;
  camera.x -= width / 2;
  camera.y -= height / 2;
}

function addFood(num) {
  var rnd = random(1, 1.5);
  while (num--) {
    foods.push({
      x: random(-config.gameWidth, config.gameWidth),
      y: random(-config.gameHeight, config.gameHeight),
      mass: rnd,
      r: massToRadius(rnd),
      hue: Math.round(Math.random() * 360)
    });
  }
}

function addVirus(num) {
  while (num--) {
    viruses.push({
      x: random(-width, width),
      y: random(-height, height),
      mass: config.virusConfig.mass,
      r: massToRadius(config.virusConfig.mass)
    });
  }
}

function updateFood() {
  for (var i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < player.blobs.length; j++) {
      var b = player.blobs[j];
      var f = foods[i];
      var x = f.x - b.x;
      var y = f.y - b.y;
      var dist = Math.hypot(x, y);
      var radii = f.r + b.r;

      if (dist < radii) {
        b.mass += f.mass;
        b.r = massToRadius(b.mass);
        foods.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (foods.length < 100) {
    addFood(1);
  }
}

function drawPlayer(order) {
  var sortedArr = player.blobs.sort(function(b1, b2) {
    return b1.mass - b2.mass;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {
    var b = sortedArr[i];

    ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + config.playerConfig.hue + ", 100%, 50%)";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "hsl(" + config.playerConfig.hue + ", 100%, 45%)";
    ctx.lineWidth = config.playerConfig.border;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(b.x - camera.x, b.y - camera.y, b.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

function drawFood() {
  for (var i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
    var f = foods[i];

    ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + f.hue + ', 100%, 50%)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(f.x - camera.x, f.y - camera.y, f.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

function drawVirus() {
  for (var i = 0; i < viruses.length; i++) {
    var v = viruses[i];

    ctx.fillStyle = config.virusConfig.fill;
    ctx.strokeStyle = config.virusConfig.stroke;
    ctx.lineWidth = config.virusConfig.border;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(v.x - camera.x, v.y - camera.y, v.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

function drawPlatform(bgcol, borcol, thickness) {
  var x = -config.gameWidth - camera.x;
  var y = -config.gameHeight - camera.y;
  var w = 2 * config.gameWidth;
  var h = 2 * config.gameHeight;

  ctx.fillStyle = bgcol;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.lineWidth = thickness;
  ctx.strokeStyle = borcol;
  ctx.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
}

function drawBackground(col) {
  ctx.fillStyle = col;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

function drawGrid() {
  var gridSize = 30;    // define the space between each line
  var x = -config.gameWidth - camera.x;  // x start point
  var y = -config.gameHeight - camera.y  // y start point
  var width = 2 * config.gameWidth;
  var height = 2 * config.gameHeight;
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(var i = 0; i * gridSize < height; i++) { // draw the horizontal lines
     ctx.moveTo(x, i * gridSize + y);
     ctx.lineTo(x + width, i * gridSize + y);
  }
  for(var i = 0; i * gridSize < width; i++) {  // draw the vertical lines
     ctx.moveTo(i * gridSize + x,  y);
     ctx.lineTo(i * gridSize + x, y + height);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}

function updateAndDraw() {
  movePlayer();
  moveCamera();
  updateFood();
  handleSelfCollision();
  //handleVirusCollision();

  drawBackground("#f2fbff");
  drawPlatform("#fff", "#000", 10);
  drawGrid();
  drawFood();
  drawPlayer();
  drawVirus();

  requestAnimationFrame(updateAndDraw);
}

function handleEvent(event) {
  touchX = event.clientX;
  touchY = event.clientY;
}

function random(min, max) {
  return (min + (Math.random() * (max - min)));
}

function massToRadius(mass) {
  return 4 + Math.sqrt(mass) * 6;
}

function startTheGame() {
  evt = width < 600 ? "click" : "mousemove";
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;

  addFood(100);
  addVirus(5);
  player.blobs.push({
    x: width / 2,
    y: height / 2,
    mass: config.playerConfig.mass,
    r: massToRadius(config.playerConfig.mass),
    speed: 8
  });

  //test
  canvas.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var blobs = player.blobs.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < blobs; i++) {
      if (blobs < maxSplits) {
        splitBlob(player.blobs[i]);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  });

  addEventListener("resize", function() {
    width = innerWidth;
    height = innerHeight
  });
  // test
  canvas.addEventListener(evt, handleEvent);
  updateAndDraw();
}


startTheGame();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<title>Gaario - A simple Agario clone</title>
<canvas>Awww! Your browser doesn't support canvas.</canvas>
```

Comment: You haven't adequately explained why this is a solution to the question asked. What did you change? How is the code different from the question that was asked? Why was it not working before, and how did this resolve the problem?

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for your example?

Comment: can you explain x * gridSize in the loop